# Error with return

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to do a input dialog, if the input number is bigger than 10 it should print a special message. So I inserted the `return`, but then I get this error: `unexpected return value`.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Program extends JFrame {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            int number= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number:"));
            if(number> 10)
                return System.out.println("The number must be less that 10");
            else
                System.out.println("...");
        }
    }
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What do you expect `return System.out.println("...")` to do? `println` is a void method, and so is `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrongly understood the [`return concept`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Since the main method's return type is `void` there will be no `return`.

```
 if(number> 10)
                System.out.println("The number must be less that 10");
            else
                System.out.println("...");
```

You are just printing to console. So there is no need of that `return` statement.

As a side note use always `{}` for `if -else`

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is print the error message on the error stream, and exit with an error code, like so:

```
public class Program extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int number= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number:"));
        if(number> 10) {
            System.err.println("The number must be less that 10");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to keep that System.exit call, you need to put brackets around the if block, otherwise the else block will be "unreachable code"

Answer (score 1):

There are two core errors here:

- `main` is a `void` method so you can't return anything from it
- `System.out.println` is a void method so you couldn't return it anyway

Drop the `return` bit completely and just print the result you want instead, or make it a separate `String` method and return the result instead of printing it. If you want your program to terminate after a faulty input, just add a simple lone return:

```
if(number> 10) {
    System.out.println("The number must be less that 10");
    return;
}
else //..and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to return a value from a void method(i.e. public static void main(String[] args), which is completely invalid.
I would sugest you to consider other other class completely for this thing and then call the methods from some other class consisting the main method.

Answer (score 0):

the main method is void, it can not return anything, nor is it supposed to.

just remove the "return" keyword, and keep the print statement.

Comment: Indeed, also System.out.println does not return anything, either, it just outputs the provided text into the standard output.